# Where is the root morpheme in Modern English ambassador, embassy?

Tags: loanwords, morphology

If there were no such a word as embassy, I would consider ambassad as a root and -or as an agent derivational suffix here. But embassy makes me puzzled. 
If we accept that segmentation shold be done  like EMBASS-Y, how can we define -ador in ambassador then? as a derivational suffix?

Comment: You've asked 6 questions and gotten (fairly good) answers for most/all of them.  Might I encourage you to mark some as accepted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is embassy spelled with E but ambassador with A?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/474496/why-is-embassy-spelled-with-e-but-ambassador-with-a)

Comment: @Spencer This question seems to ask about the suffix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Embassy" is actually a variant of the word ["ambassy":](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/embassy)

> 1570–80;  variant of ambassy  < Middle French ambassee, Old French ambasce, ambaxee

*"-ador"* is [not an English suffix:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ambassador)

> 1325–75; Middle English am-, embass ( i ) adour, imbassadore  < Anglo-French ambassateur, ambassaduer  < Italian ambassatore, dialectal Italian ambassadore,  equivalent to ambass-  ( see embassy) **-atore, -adore  < Latin -ātōrem  accusative of -ātor -ator**(Emphasis added)

Note that it is not an English suffix, but Latin. we just derived the word from the Latin word, including all the affixes.

So, to answer your question, ambassador in English is a word by itself. You can't break it down to root and suffixes (no suffix as -ador in English) in English, only if you went back to its Latin roots, then can you derive the root word. So, in English, ambassador is a root by itself, for words like "ambassadorial", "ambassadorship", etc.

Comment: Right, but where is the root in embassy then?

Comment: Well, as I said, it is a variant of ambassy, just a different vowel, but it has the same root as "ambassy"

Comment: Dear Ham and Bacon! Why don't you consider ambassad (in ambassador) as a bound root here and -or as a suffix forming an agent nouns (as in other loan words :actor, director, professor etc.)? I feel quite sure that AMBASSADOR in "ambassadorial" is a stem.

Comment: "Ambassador" is a root by itself, I stated so above, and I would agree with you that "ambassadorial"'s root is "ambassador".

Comment: If you are going to quote sources, you ought to cite them.

Comment: Yes, thank you, next time I'll mention the source for sure.

Comment: *-ador* and similar endings often suggest the word has at some stage passed through Spanish

Answer (score 7):

The point is that we borrowed both *ambassador* and *embassy* whole from other languages: neither word was assembled in English. For that reason, it is better to say that the *-or* in *ambassador* is the Latin/Italian suffix, not the English one. But that is immaterial, since both suffixes come from the same Proto-Indo-European root and have similar meanings.

Both *ambassador* and *embassy* come from the Latin word ***ambactus***, "servant". Going further back in time, the etymology becomes murky. According to the *Oxford English Dictionary* (2nd edition), the Latin word may have been derived from Celtic, but that is uncertain. Alternatively, it may come from the Proto-Germanic precursor of modern Dutch/German *ambacht*. But most etymologists hold the view that the Germanic word must have been derived from either the Celtic or the Latin word.

The OED on *ambassade*:

> Adopted from Fr. *ambassade*, 15th c. *ambaxade*, ad. OSp. *ambaxada* (mod. em-), cogn. w. Pr. *ambaissada*, It. *ambasciata*, OFr. *ambassée*, (superseded by this form in -*ade*: see *ambassy*):—L. **ambactiāta* (found in med.L. as *ambaxiāta*, -*asciāta, -assiāta, -asiāta*), ppl. derivative of **ambactiāre* to go on a mission, f. *ambactia, ambaxia* (in Salic and Burgundian Laws) ‘charge, office, employment,’ n. of office f. *ambactus* a servant (? vassal, retainer). The OFr. form *ambassée* was also adopted in Eng. as *ambassy, embassy*; as was also the med.L. as *ambassiate*, etc., the forms of which appear to have been quite mixed up with those of the present word, leading to the pronunciation in 5–6 *am'bassiade, am'bassade*, and the spellings in *-ad, -ed, -et*. But Shakespeare and subseq. writers have *amba'ssade* or '*ambassade*.
>
> The origin and meaning of *ambactus* have given rise to much discussion. According to Festus ‘Ambactus apud Ennium lingua Gallica servus appellatur’; and Caesar (B.G. vi. 15) applies it to the vassals or retainers of a Gallic chief. Hence Zeuss and Glück identify it with Welsh *amaeth, ammaeth*, (for **ambaeth*) ‘husbandman, tiller of the ground,’ perh. orig. ‘tenant, retainer,’ or even ‘goer about, footman.’ Grimm finds the origin in OHG. *ambaht*, Goth. *andbahts* servant, retainer, OE. *ambeht*, ON. *ambótt* (cf. *amboht*), variously explained as f. *and* against, towards + *bak* back, or **bah* to do, or **baht* = Skr. *bhakta* devoted, and assumed to have been adopted in Gallic, or erroneously taken as Gallic by Festus. But the majority of etymologists consider the Teut. word to be an adaptation or refashioning of the Lat. or original Celtic. For the latter, Mahn (*Etym. Unt.* 145) has also proposed *ambi(amb-, amm-, am-)* about + Breton *aketuz, akeduz* ‘busy,’ hence ‘one employed about (his lord).’

Answer (score -1):

Latin word "ambactus" was from Celtc word meant "messenger" according to [Peter Berresford Ellis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Berresford_Ellis) and ambassador = ambactus +  ams (public office).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "according to Peter Berresford Ellis". Where did he say this? Why should we trust him?