# Why is embassy spelled with E but ambassador with A?

Tags: etymology

It seems both words are related to each other through French roots (*ambassade*, *ambassadeur*), both of which are spelled with an "A" in the front.

Why and when was the initial letter of "embassy" changed to "E"? Does this also occur in other words?

---

Edit:

Wiktionary gives the following etymologies for [*ambassador*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embassy):

> From Middle English *ambassadore*
>   from Anglo-Norman *ambassadeur, ambassateur*
>   from Old Italian *ambassatore, ambassadore*
>   from Old Occitan *ambaisador* (“ambassador”)
>   derivative of *ambaissa* (“service, mission, errand”)
>   from Latin *ambasiator*
>   from Gothic  (*andbahti*, “service, function”)
>   from Proto-Germanic **ambahtiją* (“service, office”)
>   derivative of Proto-Germanic **ambahtaz* (“servant”)
>   from Gaulish *ambaxtos* ("servant"; also the source of Latin *ambactus* (“vassal, servant, dependent”))
>   from Proto-Celtic **ambaxtos* (“servant”)
>   from Proto-Indo-European **h₂mbʰi-h₂eǵ-* (“drive around”)
>   from **h₂mbʰi-* (“around”) + **h₂eǵ-* (“to drive”).

and for [*embassy*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embassy):

> Modern variant of obsolete *ambassy*
>   from Middle French *ambassee* (“mission, embassy”)
>   from Old French *ambascee* (also *enbassee* (“message for a high official, official mission”))
>   from Old Italian *ambasciata*
>   from Old Occitan *ambaissada* (“embassy”)
>   derived from *ambaissa* (“message”)
>   from Late Latin *ambactia* (“service rendered”) (attested also as Latin *ambascia*)
>   from Proto-Germanic **ambahtiją* (“service”), *ambahtaz (“follower, servant”)
>
>   from Gaulish **ambactos* (“dependant, vassal”, literally “one who is sent around”)
>   from Proto-Celtic **ambaxtos* (“servant”)
>   from Proto-Indo-European **h₂mbʰi-h₂eǵ-* (“drive around”)
>   from **h₂mbʰi-* (“around”) + **h₂eǵ-* (“to drive”);
>
> compare Latin *ambactus*, Old Irish *amos, amsach* (“mercenary, servant”), Welsh *amaeth* (“tenant farm”)).

It is noticeable that all these predecessors start with an "A" sound, only the latest change introduces an "E".

Here is also clearly mentioned that *embassy* is a modern spelling, but it does not explain when or why this change occurred or if similar words have undergone the same change.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86348/discussion-on-question-by-ahemmetter-why-is-embassy-spelled-with-e-but-ambassado).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

### In French, "amb-" and "emb-" sound the same

In French,  <am> and <em> in this kind of context came to represent the same sound (some kind of open nasal vowel; the corresponding modern French phoneme is typically transcribed as /ɑ̃/). Because of this "merger", by the sixteenth century we see variation between <am> and <em> (or <an> and <en>) in the spelling of many French words, without regard for the etymological origins of the vowel.

Later on, French spelling became much more fixed and substantially more regularized, so related pairs of words like this usually are spelled consistently with <e> or <a> in present-day French (and the modern spelling often follows the etymology—I don't know whether there are any exceptions). But *embassy* and *ambassador* entered English during a time period when French spelling was still variable (similarly, English retains the digraph <oi> in the word *connoisseur* even though the modern French spelling has been revised to become *connaisseur*).

Another pair of English words that apparently have been affected by the same phenomenon is *ex***am***ple/ex***em***plary*. I wrote an answer going into more detail beneath the following question: [Spelling of Exemplary versus that of Example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447925/spelling-of-exemplary-versus-that-of-example)

A source I found while researching that answer, *[The formation and evolution of the French nasal vowels](https://books.google.com/books?id=53YbDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA87#v=onepage&q&f=false),* by Bernard L. Rochet (1976), contains the following quotes explaining how this situation developed in French:

- > in Old French – with the exception of Picard – *eN* and *aN* seem to have been in the process of merging; the extent of the merger varied according to the regions and probably also to the social classes of the speakers. This sociological conditioning of the evolution of *eN* does not receive any direct empirical support from Old French texts but is inferred from the situation described by the sixteenth century grammarians.

  (p. 87)
- > The numerous orthographic variants found at that period [the 16th century] indicate that whatever distinctions, based on the opposition *eN : aN*, were still observed, they were only the remnants of a rapidly disappearing situation. Thus, Robert Estienne (1549) acknowledges the following alternations: "*cravanter* ou *craventer*," "*ambassade* et *embassade*", "*tencer*, voyez *tanser*", "*panser* ung malade. Voyer *penser*," etc.

  (p. 96)

[Evpok♦'s answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/296/6881) to a relevant question on French SE, "[Why are “an” and “en” pronounced the same? Pourquoi « an » et « en » ont-ils la même prononciation ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/292/why-are-an-and-en-pronounced-the-same-pourquoi-an-et-en-ont-ils-la?noredirect=1&lq=1)", links to the blog post "[la nasalization](http://ancien-francais.blogspot.com/2012/02/la-nasalisation.html)", by G. Pascault, which says that the change "ẽ̩*m* > ã*m*" occurred around the 11th-13th centuries (the blog post presents it as part of a general set of changes involving nasal vowels receiving a more open pronunciation, like õ̩*n* > õ̜*n*, ĩ*n* > ẽ*n* and ü̃*n* > œ̃*n*).

### The spelling of the common prefix *en-/em-* might have been an influence

Something else that seems like it might be relevant to the use of *e* in the  spelling of *embassy* is that many French words (or English words from French) start with a prefix spelled <en>/<em>.

This prefix has a variant spelling <an>/<am> that is used  today  in only a few words (such as *ambush, anoint, annoy*), but that was used in the past in more words ( e.g. the word *emperor* has Middle English spelling variants starting with <amp> and <aump>).

The Oxford English Dictionary entry for this *en-* prefix indicates that a fair amount of interchange occurred between *an-* and *en-* spellings before they settled down into their current distributions:

> In Middle English (as in Old French, Anglo-Norman *an-* ) *en- , em-* , frequently became *an- , am-* (as ambush v., anoint v. (Latin *inunctum*), annoy v.; *anhaunse, anjoin, anvenime,* where subsequently respelt *en-*; *andetted,* subsequently *endetted, indebted*). This *an-, am-,* like the native prefix *an-* prefix1 , was often reduced to *a-* : see appair v., aprise n. Conversely, the prefix *a-* of various origin was often changed into *en-*, as in *embraid.*

Although the first syllable of *embassy* is not etymologically derived from the prefix *en-,* its spelling might have been influenced by analogy with the spelling of words containing this prefix.

Of course, a weakness of this explanation is that it does nothing to account for the use of *am-* rather than *em-* in the currently standard spelling of the word *ambassador.*

### The English pronunciation is presumably based on the spelling

I would guess that the use of the sound /ɛ/ (the vowel found in the word "dress") in the first syllable of the modern English pronunciation of *embassy* is based on the spelling.

Comment: _”Ung” malade_? Is that a typo?

Comment: @sumelic "ung" is indeed an old alternate form of "un", possibly due to pronunciation deformation (some southern french accents are still pronouncing the non-existing "g"). See [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ung#Middle_French) and [possible source](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/ung).

Comment: TIL the French for "connoisseur" is not *connoisseur*. I suppose this means I have to stop putting on a French accent to pronounce it.

Comment: @Dan We even have [an entire question about that one](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/195960).

Comment: Might this also have been affected by the [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift)?

Comment: @T.E.D.: I don't think the Great Vowel Shift is related: that refers to changes in the qualities of the vowels that were long /aː/ /eː/ /ɛː/ /iː/ /oː/ /ɔː/ /uː/ in Middle English.

Comment: @sumelic - It *primarily* affected long vowels, but it did affect short ones as well (and even some consonants). If you look at the illustration there, the changes in short 'a' and 'e' vowels in words like "law", "new", "dew", and "that" are also depicted.

Comment: @DanHulme How can you do that to us? It's like giving the first part of a sentence and then

Comment: @Mitch I was referring to the "similarly, English retains the digraph <oi> in the word *connoisseur* even though the modern French spelling has been revised to become *connaisseur*" in the answer.

Comment: @DanHulme Thanks. It was just tantalizing without the actual French version.

Comment: @T.E.D. Not short vowels – diphthongs. Diphthongs act differently from simple short vowels; they usually align with long vowels. The only short vowels given in the table are those in _that_ (which moved minimally, from [a] to [æ]), _fox_, and _cut_, neither of which is a possible candidate here.

Answer (score 12):

The *why* is pretty simple: phonetically, it sounds like it should start with an "e". Plus, when you have one word doing it, it tends to spread.

The initial "e" in "embassy" is seen as far back as Shakespeare:

> Here comes in Embassaie, the French kinges daughter.
>   <sub>[Love's Labour's Lost](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q7w2AQAAMAAJ&pg=PT11&lpg=PT11&dq="Here+comes+in+Embassaie,+the+French+kinges+daughter.".), 1598</sub>

As for other words written both ways, I think [Johnson](https://books.google.com/books?id=uodHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA813&lpg=PA813&dq=Our+authors+write+almost+indiscriminately+embassador+or+ambassador,+embassage+or+ambassage;+yet+there+is+scarce+an+example+of+ambassy,+"all+concurring+to+write+embassy".) (1755) can answer that:

> Our authors write almost indiscriminately *embassador* or *ambassador*, *embassage* or *ambassage*; yet there is scarce an example of *ambassy*, all concurring to write *embassy*.

The OED notes:

> Of [the spelling variants of *ambassador*,] *embassador*, supported by *embassy*, was much more common than ambassador in 17–18th cent., and was still the common spelling in United States in 19th cent.

Obviously, not all these spellings survived. At this point in time, nobody uses "embassador" or "ambassage".

Another word with both forms is the archaic word [embassade/ambassade](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambassade).

Some of these words also had spellings starting with neither "e" nor "a". For example, "ambassador", which dates back to [Middle English](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED1361/track?counter=2&search_id=191014), was also spelled with an initial "y", "j", and "i" (not that there was really any difference between "i" and "j" at that point). It's also relevant to note that ambassador was spelled with an "e" very early, with Chaucer being the earliest citation for both the "a" and "e" spellings of the word:

> Thambassiatours hem answerd for final.
>   <sub>[Troylus & Criseyde](https://archive.org/details/b24875387_0002/page/184), c1374</sub>

> Stilbon, that was a wis embasitour
>   <sub>[Pardoner's Tale](https://books.google.com/books?id=60Q8AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA379&lpg=PA379&dq="Stilbon,+that+was+a+wis+embasitour"), c1386</sub>

Comment: 'it sounds like it should start with an "e"' er... why? This sounds like pure preference to me.

Comment: @TylerH The OED mentions "phonetic forms like embassader" on its page for ambassador. So it's not *my* opinion here.

Comment: I think the OED's comment "phonetic forms like embassader" may be more about the spelling of the final syllable as "der".